# PHP: mysql query "WHERE first 3 (or 4,5,6 depending on length of string) characters = '$string'"

Tags: php, mysql

I am doing a ajax suggestion function

The user gives an input of a word (like ICE), then the ajax script passes this to a .php script and that script looks it up in the database and should suggest the word ICECREAM.

This is where I am stuck. I need a query which goes like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE first str_len($string) characters = $string
```

Could you help me out please?

Answer (score 3):

You want [`LIKE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) for this.

```
SELECT
 ...
WHERE
  field LIKE '$string%'
```

Comment: Just dont forget proper escape -- rather use prepared statements with PDO or MySQLi, never ever $string in a query!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE first LIKE 'string%'
```

Comment: I don't think you'd want the leading wildcard in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
$length = strlen($input);
$statement = $pdoObject->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE LEFT(first, $length) = :input");
$statement->execute(array(':input' => $input));
```

This is safe because `$length` is guaranteed to be an integer so no need to make it a parameter.